# Win32 wont let me draw multiple lines

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to create a program with the Win32 api in c++ to draw triangles. I am at the point where I have gotten bresenham's algorithm to work but for some reason whenever I try to draw more than one line it will only draw the first one. the code is split into three parts, the algorithm, the triangle function, and WinMain.

DrawLine:

```
void DrawLine(HWND hwnd, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
    //sets up "SetPixel"
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT r;

    GetClientRect(hwnd, &r);

    if (r.bottom == 0) {

        return;
    }

    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    //This is where the algorithm begins
    int d,dx,dy,x,y,yi;

    dx = x1-x0;
    dy = y1-y0;
    yi = 1;

    //Checks if we need to increase or decrease y
    if(dy < 0){
        yi = -yi;
        dy = -dy;
    }
    d = (2*dy)-dx;

    x = x0;
    y = y0;


    for(int i = 0;i <= dx;i++){
        SetPixel(hdc,x,y,RGB(0,0,0));
        if(d > 0){
            y += yi;
            d += 2*(dy-dx);
        } else {
            d += 2*dy;
        }

        x++;
    }
}
```

DrawTriangle:

```
void DrawTriangle(HWND hwnd, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
    DrawLine(hwnd, x0, y0, x1, y1);
    DrawLine(hwnd, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    DrawLine(hwnd, x2, y2, x0, y0);
}
```

WinMain:

```
#include <windows.h>

void DrawLine(HWND hwnd, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1);
void DrawTriangle(HWND hwnd, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);

using namespace std;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
int WINAPI 
WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {

    MSG  msg;
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Pixels";
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Pixels",
                WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                100, 100, 300, 250, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    switch(msg) {

        case WM_PAINT:
            DrawTriangle(hwnd, 40, 30, 60, 20, 100, 80);
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:

            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Important note: Every change we have to make to the code you present in order to make a workable example is an opportunity for us to insert a new bug and give wrong answers based on that new bug or accidentally fix the mistake and give you no answer. Plus it makes it harder for the askers that follow you to draw the connection between your code and any answers it your question receives. It is in your best interests to provide a complete working example, preferrable as a [mre], the we can drop into our tools and see exactly what you see (excepting undefined behaviour, of course)

Comment: @user4581301 the code I presented is only three lines off from a minimal reproducible example, but thanks for bringing that to my attention

Comment: Each time you call `BeginPaint`, you start a new paint cycle, and you never call `EndPaint` to complete it. You should call `BeginPaint` once at the start of `WM_PAINT` processing and `EndPaint` once at the end. Then all the drawing occurs inside a single paint cycle.

Comment: @RaymondChen The thing that confuses me is that I do call endpaint in the DrawLine function.  That was the first thing I thought it might be but I dont know why if I am calling the endpaint function it still wouldnt work.

Comment: BeginPaint (without a custom WM_ERASEBKGND handler) clears the background, so the first two DrawLine calls get "painted over". That is why BeginPaint/EndPaint should be part of WM_PAINT and not hidden further down in your functions.

Comment: What is wrong with `LineTo`?

Comment: @PaulSanders, nothing, im doing it this way for learning experience

Comment: I don't see any occurrence of `EndPaint` anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir In this case, the first DrawLine opens a paint cycle, which marks the contents as painted. The second and third calls to BeginPaint create an empty paint cycle because the system says "Nothing was invalidated, so there is nothing to repaint", and you get an empty DC that ignores all painting. That's why only the first line survives.

Comment: @RaymondChen my mistake, I must have missed that line in when I was copying it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DrawTriangle()`/`DrawLine()` functions are taking in an `HWND` as input when they should be taking in an `HDC` instead.  Every call to `DrawLine()` is calling `BeginPaint()` (but not `EndPaint()`!) to obtain a new `HDC` from the `HWND`, which can trigger the `HWND` to immediately repaint over any existing content before allowing you to then paint new stuff onto the `HDC`.

You need to move `BeginPaint()` into your `WM_PAINT` handler, and then pass the resulting `HDC` to `DrawTriangle()`, eg:

```
void DrawLine(HDC hdc, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {

    //This is where the algorithm begins
    int d,dx,dy,x,y,yi;
    
    dx = x1-x0;
    dy = y1-y0;
    yi = 1;
    
    //Checks if we need to increase or decrease y
    if(dy < 0){
        yi = -yi;
        dy = -dy;
    }
    d = (2*dy)-dx;
    
    x = x0;
    y = y0;
    
    for(int i = 0;i <= dx;i++){
        SetPixel(hdc,x,y,RGB(0,0,0));
        if(d > 0){
            y += yi;
            d += 2*(dy-dx);
        } else {
            d += 2*dy;
        }
    
        x++;
    }
}

void DrawTriangle(HDC hdc, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
    DrawLine(hdc, x0, y0, x1, y1);
    DrawLine(hdc, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    DrawLine(hdc, x2, y2, x0, y0);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    
    switch(msg) {
    
        case WM_PAINT: {

            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            RECT r;    
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &r);

            if (r.bottom != 0)
                DrawTriangle(ps.hdc, 40, 30, 60, 20, 100, 80);

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            break;
        }
    
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```